# Limit IntegerUpDown to a specific set of numbers on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, integerupdown

I am new to WPF, and there is something I need to do but just couldnt find no where how to do it (I do know it should be possible since there is a similar object on C# forms) I want to limit the dataset of IntegerUpDown on a wpf form s.t the default value will be 1 up to 64 as powers of two, problem is there is no place (by my google search and  the microsoft website) that tells me how to do that, any help?

I think ill go with the combobox but do you have any clue why it might not recognize the style? (its on the same file...) im adding the combobox as is -

```
    <xctk:ComboBox Canvas.Left="334" Canvas.Top="80" FormatString="" 
        Maximum="64" Minimum="2" Name="integerUpDownFrameAvg" Style="{StaticResource myComboBoxStyle}" 
        Text="0" Value="0" Width="60" DataContext="{Binding}">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="1"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="2"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="4"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="8"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="16"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="32"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="64"></ComboBoxItem>
    </xctk:ComboBox>
```

that is the style -

```
<Style x:Key="myComboBoxStyle"
   TargetType="xctk:ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
      Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
      Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
      Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
      Value="#FF4A4A3C" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
      Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Width"
      Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="Height"
      Value="20" />
```

and I included the -

```
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

on the header, it dosent work though the error is missing an assembly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then why don't you use a `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox Name="intComboBox">  
    <ComboBoxItem Content="1"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="2"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="4"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="8"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="16"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="32"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="64"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I did - this is not what im looking for though, I need the increment to be as power of two (i.e. 1,2,4,8,16,32,64, and limit the maximum only limit the the top most value)

Comment: @crazyPixel: I'm sorry, I misunderstood you. I updated my answer.

Comment: That is what I know from C# forms problem is the engineer who started the whole app before me decided to use IntegerUpDown, as far as I understood he extended the integerupdown to customize it's style I tried to apply the same style on the combox with no use...(sorry that it seems like im "asking" for a full answer but problem is that sitting around and study about wpf properly will take more time than what I have to finish the app.. =\)

Comment: You could create a custom IntegerUpDown: the only things you need is a text box and two buttons. If one of the buttons is clicked, jump to the number you want.

Comment: That `xctk:` part is not even necessary: WPF has a built-in combobox. Try without `xctk:`

Comment: I noticed that only after posting the edit and earsed all the properties which are not related to combobox, no use though...I think ill just have to do a quick session on wpf and hack my way around (maybe placing a listener on the value and make the position on the dataset a power of two can work?..) tnx anyway bro I appreciate your try..

Comment: I suggest you to read the MSDN article on ComboBox Styles and Templates:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx